# How to loop an mp3 in a browser with zero gap?

Tags: silverlight, flash, mp3, ffmpeg, guitar

I'm trying to make a guitar practice website, and a critical functionality is to loop over  very short mp3 files (a few seconds long), with absolutely zero gap in between. For example, it could a 4-measures-long chord progression, and I want to allow the user to loop over it seamlessly.

I tried using the HTML5 `<audio>` tag with the `loop` attribute. Google Chrome gives a small gap between the loops, but big enough to be totally unacceptable for my purpose. I haven't tested the other browsers, but I believe it won't work.

A possible workaround is to use `ffmpeg` to stream repetitions the same audio as an mp3. However, this costs a lot of bandwidth.

For myself I use Audacity to loop without gaps, but unfortunately Audacity doesn't have a web version.

So, do you have any ideas how I may loop over an mp3 in a browser with zero gap? I prefer non-Flash solutions, but if nothing else works I'll use Flash.

**Edit:**
Thank you for all your suggestions. Flash turns out to work decently. I've made a toy demo at http://vmlucid.lcm.hk/~netvope/audio/flash.html. To my surprise (I use to associate Flash with resource hog and browser crashes only), Flash and ActionScript are rather well designed and easy to use. It took me only 3 hours on my first Flash project :)

Comment: Now that Flash is dead, I wonder if there is an HTML5 solution to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in flash AS3 you can extract sound data with [computeSpectrum()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum%28%29) and give it to your Sound object exactly when it's needed ([SampleDataEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html) is fired).

Comment: Thanks! I'll also try SampleDataEvents with ByteArrays from extract().

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this page](http://forestmist.org/2010/04/html5-audio-loops/). Listening for a while using Google Chrome 7, I found Method 1 works decently, while Method 3 gives the best results, though it's a bit of a hack. Ultimately, all browsers work differently, especially since HTML5 isn't finalized yet. If possible, you should opt for a Flash version, which I would think would give you the best loop.

Comment: Unfortunately the gap is too big. Thanks for the info though =)

Comment: @netvope- Seems like you should use Flash then

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how well this will work, but if you knew your loop lasted 800 milliseconds - you could have the browser call the play method every 800ms... it still wouldn't be guaranteed to be perfect though. I don't think the browser is natively capable of delivering reliable audio looping at this point.

```
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("loop").play();
}, 800);
```

Rumor has it the best way to do pull this off in the most gapless fashion to use to multiple audio tags and alternate between them.

Answer (score 1):

Or check out this utility: http://www.compuphase.com/mp3/mp3loops.htm I used it successfully for my flash projects when music had to be looped without gaps, and 99% of the time it worked. It takes WAV as an input.
Basically it is a kind of front-end for LAME mp3 encoder, which uses such settings as to prevent the gaps appearing. It won't work on very short sound effects (less than 0.5 second I believe).
Afterward all you have to do is use:

```
var sound:Sound = new MySoundEffect();
sound.play(0, 1000);
```

and it will loop one thousand times.

Comment: The link provides comprehensive information on gaps in mp3 files. A must-read for the curious!